# how to change monaco editor background in angular 6

Tags: monaco-editor

I have integrated the monaco editor in my angular 6 project through ngx-monaco-editor via npm. I need to customize my monaco background and could not find a way to do this.

Any idea how to change background?

Here is my `Appcomponent.ts`:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  editorOptions = {
    theme: "vs-dark",
    language: "javascript",
    fontSize: 10,
    background: "EDF9FA",
    "editor.background": "#EDF9FA"
  };

  code: string = 'function x() {\nconsole.log("Hello world!");\n}';
}
```

Is there anyway to create my own themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i have found a solution. here is the  [gitLink](https://github.com/shahin4u000/customizeMonaco-angular6), that will update the foreground of the vscode.

and the vsConfig file that u need to import in your project file.

```
import {
  MonacoEditorModule,
  NgxMonacoEditorConfig
} from 'ngx-monaco-editor';

const monacoConfig: NgxMonacoEditorConfig = {
  onMonacoLoad: () => {
    monaco.editor.defineTheme("myCustomTheme", {
      base: "vs", // can also be vs-dark or hc-black
      inherit: true, // can also be false to completely replace the builtin rules
      rules: [
        {
          token: "comment",
          foreground: "ffa500",
          fontStyle: "italic underline"
        },
        { token: "comment.js", foreground: "008800", fontStyle: "bold" },
        { token: "comment.css", foreground: "0000ff" } // will inherit fontStyle from `comment` above
      ],
      colors: {
        "editor.background": '#ffffff', // code background
        'editorCursor.foreground': '#002438', // corsour color
        'editor.lineHighlightBackground': '#9B9B9B', // line highlight colour
        'editorLineNumber.foreground': '#666666', // line number colour
        'editor.selectionBackground': '#666666', // code selection background
        'editor.inactiveSelectionBackground': '#7e890b'
      }
    });
    monaco.editor.setTheme('myCustomTheme');
  }
};

export default monacoConfig;


// A list of color names:
/* 'foreground' // Overall foreground color. This color is only used if not overridden by a component.
'errorForeground' // Overall foreground color for error messages. This color is only used if not overridden by a component.
'descriptionForeground' // Foreground color for description text providing additional information, for example for a label.
'focusBorder' // Overall border color for focused elements. This color is only used if not overridden by a component.
'contrastBorder' // An extra border around elements to separate them from others for greater contrast.
'contrastActiveBorder' // An extra border around active elements to separate them from others for greater contrast.
'selection.background' // The background color of text selections in the workbench (e.g. for input fields or text areas). Note that this does not apply to selections within the editor.
'textSeparator.foreground' // Color for text separators.
'textLink.foreground' // Foreground color for links in text.
'textLink.activeForeground' // Foreground color for active links in text.
'textPreformat.foreground' // Foreground color for preformatted text segments.
'textBlockQuote.background' // Background color for block quotes in text.
'textBlockQuote.border' // Border color for block quotes in text.
'textCodeBlock.background' // Background color for code blocks in text.
'widget.shadow' // Shadow color of widgets such as find/replace inside the editor.
'input.background' // Input box background.
'input.foreground' // Input box foreground.
'input.border' // Input box border.
'inputOption.activeBorder' // Border color of activated options in input fields.
'input.placeholderForeground' // Input box foreground color for placeholder text.
'inputValidation.infoBackground' // Input validation background color for information severity.
'inputValidation.infoBorder' // Input validation border color for information severity.
'inputValidation.warningBackground' // Input validation background color for information warning.
'inputValidation.warningBorder' // Input validation border color for warning severity.
'inputValidation.errorBackground' // Input validation background color for error severity.
'inputValidation.errorBorder' // Input validation border color for error severity.
'dropdown.background' // Dropdown background.
'dropdown.foreground' // Dropdown foreground.
'dropdown.border' // Dropdown border.
'list.focusBackground' // List/Tree background color for the focused item when the list/tree is active. An active list/tree has keyboard focus, an inactive does not.
'list.focusForeground' // List/Tree foreground color for the focused item when the list/tree is active. An active list/tree has keyboard focus, an inactive does not.
'list.activeSelectionBackground' // List/Tree background color for the selected item when the list/tree is active. An active list/tree has keyboard focus, an inactive does not.
'list.activeSelectionForeground' // List/Tree foreground color for the selected item when the list/tree is active. An active list/tree has keyboard focus, an inactive does not.
'list.inactiveSelectionBackground' // List/Tree background color for the selected item when the list/tree is inactive. An active list/tree has keyboard focus, an inactive does not.
'list.inactiveSelectionForeground' // List/Tree foreground color for the selected item when the list/tree is inactive. An active list/tree has keyboard focus, an inactive does not.
'list.hoverBackground' // List/Tree background when hovering over items using the mouse.
'list.hoverForeground' // List/Tree foreground when hovering over items using the mouse.
'list.dropBackground' // List/Tree drag and drop background when moving items around using the mouse.
'list.highlightForeground' // List/Tree foreground color of the match highlights when searching inside the list/tree.
'pickerGroup.foreground' // Quick picker color for grouping labels.
'pickerGroup.border' // Quick picker color for grouping borders.
'button.foreground' // Button foreground color.
'button.background' // Button background color.
'button.hoverBackground' // Button background color when hovering.
'badge.background' // Badge background color. Badges are small information labels, e.g. for search results count.
'badge.foreground' // Badge foreground color. Badges are small information labels, e.g. for search results count.
'scrollbar.shadow' // Scrollbar shadow to indicate that the view is scrolled.
'scrollbarSlider.background' // Slider background color.
'scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground' // Slider background color when hovering.
'scrollbarSlider.activeBackground' // Slider background color when active.
'progressBar.background' // Background color of the progress bar that can show for long running operations.
'editor.background' // Editor background color.
'editor.foreground' // Editor default foreground color.
'editorWidget.background' // Background color of editor widgets, such as find/replace.
'editorWidget.border' // Border color of editor widgets. The color is only used if the widget chooses to have a border and if the color is not overridden by a widget.
'editor.selectionBackground' // Color of the editor selection.
'editor.selectionForeground' // Color of the selected text for high contrast.
'editor.inactiveSelectionBackground' // Color of the selection in an inactive editor.
'editor.selectionHighlightBackground' // Color for regions with the same content as the selection.
'editor.findMatchBackground' // Color of the current search match.
'editor.findMatchHighlightBackground' // Color of the other search matches.
'editor.findRangeHighlightBackground' // Color the range limiting the search.
'editor.hoverHighlightBackground' // Highlight below the word for which a hover is shown.
'editorHoverWidget.background' // Background color of the editor hover.
'editorHoverWidget.border' // Border color of the editor hover.
'editorLink.activeForeground' // Color of active links.
'diffEditor.insertedTextBackground' // Background color for text that got inserted.
'diffEditor.removedTextBackground' // Background color for text that got removed.
'diffEditor.insertedTextBorder' // Outline color for the text that got inserted.
'diffEditor.removedTextBorder' // Outline color for text that got removed.
'merge.currentHeaderBackground' // Current header background in inline merge-conflicts.
'merge.currentContentBackground' // Current content background in inline merge-conflicts.
'merge.incomingHeaderBackground' // Incoming header background in inline merge-conflicts.
'merge.incomingContentBackground' // Incoming content background in inline merge-conflicts.
'merge.commonHeaderBackground' // Common ancestor header background in inline merge-conflicts.
'merge.commonContentBackground' // Common ancester content background in inline merge-conflicts.
'merge.border' // Border color on headers and the splitter in inline merge-conflicts.
'editorOverviewRuler.currentContentForeground' // Current overview ruler foreground for inline merge-conflicts.
'editorOverviewRuler.incomingContentForeground' // Incoming overview ruler foreground for inline merge-conflicts.
'editorOverviewRuler.commonContentForeground' // Common ancestor overview ruler foreground for inline merge-conflicts.
'editor.lineHighlightBackground' // Background color for the highlight of line at the cursor position.
'editor.lineHighlightBorder' // Background color for the border around the line at the cursor position.
'editor.rangeHighlightBackground' // Background color of highlighted ranges, like by quick open and find features.
'editorCursor.foreground' // Color of the editor cursor.
'editorWhitespace.foreground' // Color of whitespace characters in the editor.
'editorIndentGuide.background' // Color of the editor indentation guides.
'editorLineNumber.foreground' // Color of editor line numbers.
'editorRuler.foreground' // Color of the editor rulers.
'editorCodeLens.foreground' // Foreground color of editor code lenses
'editorBracketMatch.background' // Background color behind matching brackets
'editorBracketMatch.border' // Color for matching brackets boxes
'editorOverviewRuler.border' // Color of the overview ruler border.
'editorGutter.background' // Background color of the editor gutter. The gutter contains the glyph margins and the line numbers.
'editorError.foreground' // Foreground color of error squigglies in the editor.
'editorError.border' // Border color of error squigglies in the editor.
'editorWarning.foreground' // Foreground color of warning squigglies in the editor.
'editorWarning.border' // Border color of warning squigglies in the editor.
'editorMarkerNavigationError.background' // Editor marker navigation widget error color.
'editorMarkerNavigationWarning.background' // Editor marker navigation widget warning color.
'editorMarkerNavigation.background' // Editor marker navigation widget background.
'editorSuggestWidget.background' // Background color of the suggest widget.
'editorSuggestWidget.border' // Border color of the suggest widget.
'editorSuggestWidget.foreground' // Foreground color of the suggest widget.
'editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground' // Background color of the selected entry in the suggest widget.
'editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground' // Color of the match highlights in the suggest widget.
'editor.wordHighlightBackground' // Background color of a symbol during read-access, like reading a variable.
'editor.wordHighlightStrongBackground' // Background color of a symbol during write-access, like writing to a variable.
'peekViewTitle.background' // Background color of the peek view title area.
'peekViewTitleLabel.foreground' // Color of the peek view title.
'peekViewTitleDescription.foreground' // Color of the peek view title info.
'peekView.border' // Color of the peek view borders and arrow.
'peekViewResult.background' // Background color of the peek view result list.
'peekViewResult.lineForeground' // Foreground color for line nodes in the peek view result list.
'peekViewResult.fileForeground' // Foreground color for file nodes in the peek view result list.
'peekViewResult.selectionBackground' // Background color of the selected entry in the peek view result list.
'peekViewResult.selectionForeground' // Foreground color of the selected entry in the peek view result list.
'peekViewEditor.background' // Background color of the peek view editor.
'peekViewEditorGutter.background' // Background color of the gutter in the peek view editor.
'peekViewResult.matchHighlightBackground' // Match highlight color in the peek view result list.
'peekViewEditor.matchHighlightBackground' // Match highlight color in the peek view editor.
 */
```

Comment: Where does the variable monaco come from on Line 7?
PS: I checked out the link -> it imports the config from './monaco', which does not exist in the repository

Comment: You can add the following   'editorLineNumber.activeForeground' // Line number color for active line